# IIS 8.5 getting 404 for some images and not others in same folder

Tags: http-status-code-404, iis-8.5

I've seen a number of posts about getting a 404 for all files or all files of a certain type.

In my case, some files can be accessed and some can't.

I open IIS, click on the website and switch to Content View. I right click on an image and click Browse and it comes up in IE. However, I can copy a file to the server, do the same steps as above in the same folder and it comes up with a 404.
I checked the permissions on the image I copied and they're the same as the existing ones.

Every existing file opens and every new file I copy to the same folder fails.

This server is a clone of another. All the images that work were on the original server. I don't think this should matter but I thought it was worth mentioning.

I'm at a loss of what to try next.

Comment: Confirm the status/substatus codes first, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Then you might use tools like Process Monitor if 404.0 is hit.

Comment: So this is embarrassing... the DNS was never switched over to the cloned server. Some files worked because they were still on the old server that the DNS was pointing to. Sorry for wasting peoples time.